# Creating a table with procedure parameter values PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, types, procedure

My task is to transfer a list of values ​​​​from excel to Oracle and create a table based on them.
As I see the solution: I need a procedure with input parameters - comma-separated values. For example: parameter1 := 'aaa','bbb','ccc' etc. no more than 100 values.
and a second parameter with the same number of values ​​parameter2 := 'xxx','yyy','jjj'...
As a result, there should be a table in Oracle with two columns and values ​​assigned to the input parameters.
I know you can create a type table, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Tab1 (col VARCHAR2(3));
 
CREATE TYPE t_Tab1 IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(3) ; 
 
DECLARE 
 
v_tbl t_Tab1 := t_Tab1 ('aaa','bbb','ccc');
 
BEGIN
  
INSERT INTO Tab1
SELECT VALUE (t)
FROM TABLE (v_tbl) t;
 
COMMIT;
END;
```

But I can't figure out how to add a second column and accept values ​​from procedure parameters. Perhaps there is a more convenient option, thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you try searching for **excel file to oracle database table** ? I believe that at least one of the [nearly] 9.5 million results will help you.

Comment: Abra
 Yes, I did search, but unfortunately I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create the table with as many columns as you need (i,e., matching the Excel). Depending on the data quality, you may create all columns as `VARCHAR2(4000)`, even it looks like a date or number. Most Excel files have non-numeric data in date or number columns
2. If there are few rows (say < 10000), you can use Excel formula to generate insert statements, something like `="INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES ('" & B1 & "', '" & B2 & ... & "');"`
3. If there are many rows (say hundreds of thousand), you can save as CSV and use SQL Loader to load the data. Since Oracle 12c there is an express mode ([12.2 doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-express-mode.html#GSUTIL3963)) which makes this an easy task, the command is something like

   sqlldr hr TABLE=mytable CSV=WITH_EMBEDDED DATA=mydata.csv

It is very likely that some rows fail for step 2 or 3. Therefore, be prepared for the need to truncate the table and fine tune.